# How to count number of inversions in an array using segment trees

Tags: c++, arrays, segment-tree

I know that this problem can be solved using modified merge sort and I have coded same. Now I want to solve this problem using **Segment Tree**. Basically, if we traverse from right to left array then we have to count the "*how many values are greater than current value*". How this thing can be achieved by Segment Tree?

What type of information we have to store on **Segment Tree Node**?

Please provide code if possible.

Answer (score 8):

Let me explain step by step with an example:

```
arr      :  4 3 7 1
position :  0 1 2 3
```

First, sort the array in descending order as {value, index} pair.

```
arr      :  7 4 3 1
index    :  2 0 1 3
position :  0 1 2 3
```

Iterating from left to right, for each element `arr[i]` -

Query for each element's `index` (query for range `[0, arr[i].index]` to get the greater numbers count on left side) and put the query result on corresponding `index` of output array.

After each query, increment the corresponding segment tree node which covers that `index`.

This way, we are ensuring to get only greater numbers count from `0` to `index - 1` as values only greater than `arr[i]` have been inserted so far.

Below C++ implementation will make more sense.

```
class SegmentTree {

    vector<int> segmentNode;

public:
    void init(int n) {
        int N = /* 2 * pow(2, ceil(log((double) n / log(2.0)))) - 1 */ 4 * n;
        segmentNode.resize(N, 0);
    }

    void insert(int node, int left, int right, const int indx) {
        if(indx < left or indx > right) {
            return;
        }
        if(left == right and indx == left) {
            segmentNode[node]++;
            return;
        }
        int leftNode = node << 1;
        int rightNode = leftNode | 1;
        int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;

        insert(leftNode, left, mid, indx);
        insert(rightNode, mid + 1, right, indx);

        segmentNode[node] = segmentNode[leftNode] + segmentNode[rightNode];
    }

    int query(int node, int left, int right, const int L, const int R) {
        if(left > R or right < L) {
            return 0;
        }
        if(left >= L and right <= R) {
            return segmentNode[node];
        }

        int leftNode = node << 1;
        int rightNode = leftNode | 1;
        int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;

        return query(leftNode, left, mid, L, R) + query(rightNode, mid + 1, right, L, R);
    }

};

vector<int> countGreater(vector<int>& nums) {
    vector<int> result;
    if(nums.empty()) {
        return result;
    }
    int n = (int)nums.size();
    vector<pair<int, int> > data(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        data[i] = pair<int, int>(nums[i], i);
    }
    sort(data.begin(), data.end(), greater<pair<int, int> >());
    result.resize(n);
    SegmentTree segmentTree;
    segmentTree.init(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        result[data[i].second] = segmentTree.query(1, 0, n - 1, 0, data[i].second);
        segmentTree.insert(1, 0, n - 1, data[i].second);
    }
    return result;
}

// Input : 4 3 7 1
// output: 0 1 0 3
```

This is easy one but not pretty "obvious" as other typical segment tree problem. Simulating with pen and paper with an arbitrary input will help.

There are other `O(nlogn)` approaches with BST, Fenwick tree and merge sort.

Answer (score 1):

It is solved quite simply. We construct an empty segment tree of size `n` with the operation sum. Now go through the permutation elements from left to right. A one in a leaf of a tree of segments will mean that such an element was already visited. When moving to the `i-th` element of `p[i]`, we will make a request to calculate the sum of `[p[i],n]` in the segment tree: it will just count the number of elements to the left which are greater than `p[i]`. And finally, put one in position `p[i]`. The total time is `O(nlogn)`.